# What's the difference between `yum install <local path>` and `yum localinstall <local path>`

Tags: yum, rpm

If I have an RPM located on a local disk -
what is the diffrefence between the following `yum` commands?

```
sudo yum install /tmp/rpm_name.rpm
sudo yum localinstall /tmp/rpm_name.rpm
```

*Note:*
I use RedHat/CentOS 7.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In RHEL 5 and previous versions, `yum install` only accepted package names from enabled repositories, and did not accept paths to local RPMs; you had to use `yum localinstall` to install these.

In RHEL 6 and later, `yum install` accepts both package names and local filenames, so `localinstall` is no longer necesary, but it's included for backward compatibility.

In RHEL 8, `dnf localinstall` is simply an alias for `dnf install`.

Comment: In RHEL 6 and 7, what's the difference, if it wasn't simply an alias until 8? Is it that `localinstall` _only_ accepts paths until 8?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Right, `localinstall` was the old code and only accepts local paths through RHEL 7. In 8, the old code is gone and `localinstall` is simply `install`.

Answer (score 5):

Note that in CentOS7 there is a subtle difference

`sudo yum install <alreadyExistingPackage>`

will give an error `Error: Nothing to do`

but the

`sudo yum localinstall <alreadyExistingPackage>`

will not give an error

If you run your script with -e option

```
#!/bin/bash -e
```

you will notice this difference